# lightning:container can not load HTML from static resource

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I tried to include an html file inside Salesforce lightning container which will run our react js app.

I believe I missed some setting. We could directly access the static resource but it showing nothing on the lightning community page.

```
    <lightning:container
            src='/portal/resource/portal_resource/index.html'

            onmessage="{!c.handleMessage}"
            onerror="{!c.handleError}"/>

    <lightning:container
            src='/resource/portal_resource/index.html'
            onmessage="{!c.handleMessage}"
            onerror="{!c.handleError}"/>

    <lightning:container
            src='resource/portal_resource/index.html'
            onmessage="{!c.handleMessage}"
            onerror="{!c.handleError}"/>
```

[image: inline]

Community URL： https://portal-dev-community-developer-edition.na53.force.com/portal/s/

Static resource : https://portal-dev-community-developer-edition.na53.force.com/portal/resource/PortalApp/index.html

```
    <lightning:container
            aura:id="PortalApp"
            src="resource/PortalApp/index.html"
            onmessage="{!c.handleMessage}"
            onerror="{!c.handleError}"/>
    <lightning:container
            aura:id="PortalApp"
            src="/portal/resource/PortalApp/index.html"
            onmessage="{!c.handleMessage}"
            onerror="{!c.handleError}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  The communities site is a different domain.  It may not like the relative URI.  The $Resource global variable should get around that.

```
<lightning:container
        src="{!$Resource.portal_resource + '/index.html'}"
        onmessage="{!c.handleMessage}"
        onerror="{!c.handleError}"/>
```

You could also try

```
src='/{your-community-page-name}/resource/portal_resource/index.html'
```

Comment: None of your solutions works. It's so strange and odd. Is there any security setting that we need to update it? https://portal-dev-community-developer-edition.na53.force.com/portal/s/

Comment: Hmm.  Well that stinks!  :P   Are you logged in as a community user, or are you accessing the page as the Guest User?

Comment: Ooh -- better question:  What's your static resource?  Is it a zip file, or just an HTML file?

Comment: Appreciate your update. I'm accessing as internal/guest/community users. None of them could see the content. As you can see. You could directly access my static resource, isn't it? Any thought?

Comment: What have you uploaded to your static resource?  Is it a zip file?  An html file on its own?  Let's make sure it isn't a path issue!

Comment: ...and, in the meantime, give this a try:   src="{!$Resource.portal_resource + '/index.html'}"    (We'll get there!)

Comment: Is this issue solved? I am trying to load the static resource from helper js not working for the portal.

Comment: @ChinmayaHegde -- I'm not sure. Go ahead and open another thread in case the issue you're having is different.